# Rails inheritance and migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and I am trying to complete a little project for my undergrad. The application will have a REST api, and I want every api resource to have an api_guid attribute.

Is there a way to tell this to the "rails generate model" command line? Like, if belongs to super class ApiResource include api_guid cloumn.

Whats the best way to store the guid on mysql? I am currently saving it as a string.

Thank in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `--parent` option for `rails generate model` (just run it without arguments to get the documentation), but that seems to want to give you single table inheritance (basically Rails will store all of your data in the same table which has the name of the superclass and will use the `type` field to distinguish between the subclasses).

Also we use GUIDs as strings in production and that works fine for us.

Comment: Thanks Josh, this really seems to be the only 'standard' way to go as far as I read.Thats what I decided to do:
- Create a ApiResourceInfo model, which only have the guid attribute for now.
- Create a one to one relationship for every instance which needs ApiResource's behaviour.

Now I need to figure out how to create a new ApiResourceInfo everytime I create an instance that needs it. Is there a way to define callbacks in a module and just include it in the models that needs them?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, take a look at ActiveSupport::Concerns (or concerns in general). As far as as I know that's the de-facto way to elegantly add ActiveRecord callbacks (and other macro-style callbacks) but still keep them encapsulated